# Bots, bots everywhere (a.k.a. I need a "report this suggested edit" button)

Tags: discussion

First of all, congratulations for tricking me into reviewing a suggested edit by showing me a dialog that informs me that I now have the privilege to review suggested edits, and then serving me, without asking me first, with the suggested edit queue.

Now on to the subject of this post.

Here is a suggested edit that I saw in the queue:

[image]

As you can see, the edits are ***complete and utter garbage***, probably auto-generated random words.

Then, here is the profile of the suggester:

[image]

Yeah.
I think we need a "report this edit suggestion" button.  So that things like this can be eliminated quickly.  Killed.  With fire.

Comment: Did you select "Reject" and submitted? I am pretty sure the next thing you see is "Congratulations - this was just a test - you passed".

Comment: See [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: @DocBrown oh, ok. I see. Thanks. I believe I did reject, (I mean, what else could I have done?) but I do not recall receiving any "congratulations" message.

Comment: Don't mind, when I saw this kind of audit the first time, it puzzled me, too ;-) Nice to see you did not give up on contributing to SE.SE completely.